# How to split a javascript array using Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a project that outputs a huge array, and I need to clean it up to send in an email. It seems the simplest approach is the split() function, but I can't seem to make it work.

```
function splitArray() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var row = ss.getLastRow();
var range = ss.getRange(row, 1, 1, ss.getMaxColumns());
var data = range.getValues();
data.split("\n");
Logger.log(data);}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the return value of `data.split("\n");` to something.
You are splitting the value successfully but not storing that value anywhwere

Try:

```
data = data.split("\n");
```

or

```
Logger.log(data.split("\n"));
```

Comment: This looks great, except that Google returns this: "TypeError: Cannot find function split in object". I'm not sure Google Apps Script recognizes the split function.

Comment: Seems like data is already an array. Try logging data before doing the split